# Who turned The Count?

Tags: vampire, sesame-street

On Sesame Street, who “turned” The Count? Or, if he is the original vampire, has he ever turned anyone into one of his thralls? Any scenes which *might* be taken as evidence that he has done so?

Comment: you sure he *is* a vampire? http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Is_the_Count_on_Sesame_Street_a_vampire%3F

Comment: I have several theories. One. Two. Three theories. Blah!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_von_Count - This suggests that vampirism is a family trait

Comment: @NKCampbell I'll believe those claims once I have definite evidence that the media that posits he isn't a vampire was not funded by a Transylvanian holding company...

Comment: This question has fifteen upvotes. One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, ah, ah, ah!

Answer (score 9):

The Count was interviewed by WIRED in a video released February 22, 2017 (WIRED (2017-02-22), The Cast of 'Sesame Street' Answer the Web's Most Searched Questions | WIRED, retrieved 2017-03-01). In the interview, he says he will be 6,523,728 years old "next October.

According to the Noddist book of Enoch, this places him in Enoch (the first city) as a companion of at least the antediluvians. His counting obsession suggests a lineage from Malkav, but in the credits of *Sesame Street* movie *Follow That Bird* the Count appeared on-screen during the closing credits  where he proceeded to read and count the credits. He also says "Hi, Mom" when a credit appears for Joan Ganz Cooney, creator of Sesame Street.

This suggests that Cooney is his sire, making his lineage Caine - Enoch - Malkav - Cooney - Count. A powerful 5th Generation - thus explaining his potency and occult powers. He has been observed with his 'children' - the bats - Sasha, Misha, Grisha and Tatiana, but it is unclear if they are his children or his pets.

He has made mention of Uncles, brothers, grandparents and a mother and the presence of Countess Von Backwards, Countess Dahling Von Dahling and 'The Countess' demonstrate others with the same clan insanity suggesting either a shared sire (Cooney?) or offspring.

In terms of the Count turning anyone, there is [this video evidence](https://youtu.be/lQALLGsn-Fk) of a vampire attack on a hapless actor, which occurred after the newly sired vampire's interaction with The Count in a *Great Muppet Caper*.